# Break or pause mirroring in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I would like to run upgrade scripts on various databases in SQL Server which we have in a mirrored set-up **(no witness)**.

Do I break or pause the mirroring?

Also, do I run the scripts on the **Passive Mode** as well or let the databases on there sync with the upgraded master?

Thanks.

Comment: This question should be asked in `dba.stackexchange.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below commands to pause mirroring

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDBName SET PARTNER SUSPEND
```

...to resume

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDBName SET PARTNER RESUME
```

You aren't able to run scripts on the mirror because its databases are in recovery mode. I don't think you should stop the mirroring.